# Unable to retrive some regedit entries using *REG QUERY* command

Tags: windows, command

I am using **REG QUERY HKLM/SOFTWARE** command to retrieve all installed soft wares,
but its not returning few of applications, what ever the application I needed is a 64 bit one.

OS:- Windows 7

Note:- When I use the command its returning the applications which are under **[Wow6432Node]** folder, but my application is not presented under this folder. Its present under **[HKLM/SOFTWARE]** location

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is due to the [registry redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa384232.aspx). You are running the 32 bit version of `REG`, presumably because the process that invokes it is a 32 bit process. And so the 32 bit version of `REG` reads the 32 bit view of the registry by default.

You should use /reg:64 switch to force reg to use the 64 bit view of the registry, as described here: [MS-KB-948698](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948698).

If you are doing this from a program then it's better to use the registry API to read entries than using the `REG` tool.

Comment: But for Windows 7, they do not provided any info about this hot fix.

Comment: You don't need a hotfix on Windows 7. You simply need to use /reg:64